# Why can't the compiler infer my generic type? (But the intellisense can)

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I have this generic class

```
public class SomeClass<TA>{
  public SomeClass(Func<IList<TA> myFunc){...}
  public OtherClass<TA, TM> CreateOther<TM>(Func<TA, Func<TM>> func) {...}
```

When I call the `CreateOther` method, I have to specify `TM` explicitely. Otherwise the code does not compile with "Type arguments cannnot be inferred from usage".

```
mySomeClass.CreateOther<string>(a=>a.GiveString)

//with
public class StringGiver{
  public string GiveString() => "Hello";
}
//and
var creatorFunc = ()=> new List<StringGiver> {new ()};
var mySomeClass = new MySomeClass(creatorFunc);
```

From my understanding it should be possible to infer TM from the return type of `GiveString`. In fact when I write the above line, the `<string>` part will be grayed out by my Intellisense/ReSharper with the hint "Type argument specification is redundant".

I do not rely on constrains like similar infer generic type questions here [Why doesn't C# infer my generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511066/why-doesnt-c-sharp-infer-my-generic-types) [Why can't these generic type parameters be inferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990275/why-cant-these-generic-type-parameters-be-inferred). So I don't think this is a duplicate.

[Fiddle]https://dotnetfiddle.net/ftNgNG based on Panagiotis Kanavos
efford

Comment: What version of C# and dotnet are we talking about?

Comment: What is `GiveString`? Post something others can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Fildor No, it's likely a method group, which can be converted to a `Func<string>`.

Comment: For the Version: I get the same behavior for dot net 6 and not net framework 4.8.

GiveString just returns a string. The `Func<string>` would be `a=>a.GiveString`

Comment: Right, @JohnathanBarclay ...

Comment: .NET 6 is the *oldest* supported .NET Core version. This [minimal fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/82we1n) compiles in .NET 8

Comment: But even [.NET 6 works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tvj35M). Post actual code we can try to replicate the problem and the actual full compilation error. I suspect the real problem has to do with the contents of the methods, not the signature

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the fiddle. Much appreciated. I can not share my actual code since it belongs to our customer.

The behavior in the fiddle is the same as it is for me. Line 6 `var f=mySomeClass.CreateOther<string>(a=>a.GiveString);` compiles fine, but remove the `<string>` portion and it will produce the same compile error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you misunderstood. OP meant to say that the code doesn't compile without specifying the type arguments explicitly. Of course it does compile *with* `<string>`.

Comment: @Sweeper I didn't misunderstand. I mistyped because *we don't have something to test* so I had to copy the snippets and fill the missing parts. BTW Intellisense marks this as an error, so we still don't have an example that passes Intellisense but not compilation

Comment: That said, C# isn't and will never be F#. In this case, the C# compiler will try to resolve the *delegate* first. It's like trying to write `Func<TA, Func<TM>> func=a=>a.GiveString;` and then `mySomeClass.CreateOther(func)`. That means the compiler would have to indirectly infer one delegate's arguments from the other. That's not possible yet. `Func<StringGiver, Func<string>> func=a=>a.GiveString;` on the other hand works

Comment: @gurkan XY Problem does not apply. This would be: I want to solve X and think that Y would be a solution and proceed to ask Y instead of X.
The question actually is "why can the compiler not infer the type". No ulterior thought behind it. I just want to understand. Especially since my intellisense is able to infer the type and tells me I can omit the specification.

Comment: That it is quite convoluted example from the compiler point of view - you have"nested" funcs and method group on top of it. As [written here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/129) -  _"Type inference doesn't infer based on an argument that is a method group, no matter how many or few members the method group has."_. You can read [type inference spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1263-type-inference) carefully yo try to understand why exactly it behaves that way (it maybe even a bug).

Comment: Also - more [minimal example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoAKgUwM4AuKAFAJJ4CiAbjjAJQDcmuhSxAHgAQC8AfJywIBhAHTlqtRpgD00gfgJlKNeg06zOAdygAbHZwBm0fQQD2pzJgQoAbJ2Dn94lcVgFO7Oj34EATgFccJgwrW04EABZ5QgAeLF5iBABWOIAae0d+AAdfHAATKABjCAIcOgBvAF9LDGs7SOiiOITkmLd0+M4c/KKSsqqauvCowSRmxJT28JT47NyC4tKK6pDagGZwsORGoUxyzgPMA/CNoYdTJ2VaYi8+Tj9A4JWgA==), note that `Test2(x => () => TestC.IsEven());` will not work either.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos JFYI the code in the duplicate which was used actually compiles now.

Comment: @GuruStron thanks for the links. As you already noted the inference from method groups works now. At least for simple usage like `SomeFunc(SomeMethod)`. I have this also in a different context and inference works there. I will read over the spec when I find the time. Seems not like an easy read though :)