# Why can I in C# pass a delegate variable as a generic argument, but not a method

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I have these two methods:

```
string Foo<T>(Func<T, string> f) => throw new NotImplementedException();
string Bar(int x) => x.ToString();
```

Why can I, in C#, assign a method to a variable, then pass the variable to a method:

```
var f = Bar;
Foo(f); // compiles just fine
```

But not pass the method directly?

```
Foo(Bar);
```

This gives a compile error

> The type arguments for method 'Program.Foo(Func<T, string>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Why is it that the variable assignment can infer the type, but the argument assignment can not?

**Edit:**

[Eric Lippert answered in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7748849/3282)

> Specifically, the subtle difference is that a method group is
> considered to be convertible to a delegate type solely on the basis of
> whether the arguments match, not also on the basis of whether the
> return type matches. Lambdas check both the arguments and the return
> type.

Seems like this is still the case according to [C# 12 specification and method group conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions):

> If type inference is used, the parameter types of the delegate are
> used as argument types in the inference process. The return type of
> the delegate is not used for inference

But this conflicts with [C# programming guide and delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/delegates-with-named-vs-anonymous-methods):

> Beginning with C# 10, method groups with a single overload have a
> natural type. This means the compiler can infer the return type and
> parameter types for the delegate type: `var read = Console.Read;`

This means the compiler is indeed capable of converting a method group of one to a delegate. So why doesn't it do the same when the method group is passed directly?

Comment: ["Why" questions are not good questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/5133585). Please rephrase your question so that it is clear what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: Can you show us a [mcve] that we can debug?

Comment: You can in most circumstances, when you can't it is usually because the type inference is ambiguous, however when that happens there will be an error message or warning that will explain the issue. Please edit your post to include that error message, otherwise we will have to close this as unreproducible. Also include the version of C# compiler, that will help.

Comment: Is this the error you're getting? `error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'C.Map<T>(Game, Func<Game, T, Game>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: @gunr2171 In your example there's no type inference problem.

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77678734/5133585)

Comment: He has shown all code necessary to understand the problem.
The compiler infers the type params when the method group is wrapped into a delegate variable. But he can't infer them when the method group assigned to the delegate is directly used as delegate variable. Which *seems* to make no sense since he could do the same conversion from method group to delegate here as well.

Comment: @gunr2171 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HeByqX)

Comment: Here aswell : https://dotnetfiddle.net/hKmtAQ

Comment: @gunr2171 the difference is that your repro is not using generics, while OP's has parameter of generic type in the function. Note that having generic only as return would also be fine - https://dotnetfiddle.net/DEfziK . See also discussions in question linked by Sweeper

Comment: The duplicate referred to is not the same at all. The question is 12 years old, the C# compiler has changed since then, and the compiler error is something different.

Comment: @Sweeper, I think the question is very clear, I ask why one thing is possible and why the equivalent is not. And the body shows the code (now edited) in question.

Comment: Before I vote to reopen the question, can the person who closed it as duplicate explain why it is a duplicate?

Comment: @gunr2171 you changed the meaning of my question when you replaced `var` with `Func<int, string>`. Then the point got lost that the compiler can assign a method group to a `var` and pass it as an argument just fine, but passing the method group directly does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`var f = Bar` will implicitly create a Delegate pointing to Bar. You can declare `Bar` as a delegate right away and it will work. See below.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string Foo<T>(Func<T, string> f) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        Func<int, string> Bar = x => x.ToString();
        
        var f = Bar;
        Foo(f); // compiles just fine
        
        Foo(Bar); // also compiles 
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this. That is not my question.

Answer (score 0):

> But this conflicts with C# programming guide and delegates:

I would argue that it actually does not. First of all [the natural type of a lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#natural-type-of-a-lambda-expression) doc states the following (emphasis mine):

> Beginning with C# 10, a lambda expression **may** have a natural type. Instead of forcing you to declare a delegate type, such as `Func<...>` or `Action<...>` for a lambda expression, the compiler **may** infer the delegate type from the lambda expression.

As written in this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16824):

> Type inference doesn't infer based on an argument that is a method group, no matter how many or few members the method group has. The conversion from a method group to a delegate (of some particular type) occurs after type inference has completed to determine what that delegate type is.

You can follow this [github discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/129) where language team members are discussing changes to the spec ([this part of spec, I assume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1263-type-inference)) required to implement something similar to "natural type" in this case also.

Arguably [these comments by Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229131/why-cant-c-sharp-infer-type-from-this-seemingly-simple-obvious-case#comment7312369_6231921) shed some light on the issue:

> Overload resolution cannot be attempted because overload resolution determines a method given a method group and arguments. But it is the argument types we are attempting to work out! That's a chicken-and-egg problem which we do not attempt to solve.

> Saying that "the method group contains only one method so let's provisionally say that overload resolution succeeds even if we don't know the arguments" is essentially adding a new, weird overload resolution algorithm that only succeeds in the rare case of the method group containing one method. We really don't want to go there; do you really want a situation where adding a second overload severely changes how type inference works?

P.S.

1. Note that "flipping" the types works - i.e. if generic is in the return position of `Func`:

   ```
   string Foo<T>(Func<int, T> f) => throw new NotImplementedException();
   string Bar(int x) => x.ToString();

   Foo(Bar);
   ```

- [[Proposal]: Type inference using method group natural type](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/7687) @github

Comment: You have to dumb this down for me. What I read is that the compiler can infer a method group, which is what it does when you can assign a method group to an implicitly typed variable. When the compiler has this capability, why does it fail when the assignment is to a parameter?

Comment: Also, when the compiler can infer the method group and assign it to an implicitly typed variable, then all arguments about when it can't infer does not apply.

Comment: @ThomasEyde in short - because the spec say so, the **12.6.3.1** part, which starts with _"When a generic method is called without specifying type arguments, a type inference process attempts to infer type arguments for the call."_. It will not attempt to determine (natural) type of the method group because it was not designed/implemented.